# Can't create directory with mkdirs()

Tags: java, android, file

I have an android application, which is planned to download images from given urls.
I want to create a directory named after an input, containing multiple files (.jpg).
The URL for the files is taken from an ArrayList.

Before adding files, I want to create a basic directory for my application like this:

```
String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/myApp";
                File dir = new File(file_path);
                if(!dir.exists())
                    dir.mkdirs();
                Log.i("Test","Directory created: "+dir.exists());
                File file = new File(dir, "test.jpg");
                FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                // image is the Bitmap created from one URL
                image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);
                fOut.flush();
                fOut.close();
```

I also added the permissions to the manifest-file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application [...]
```

My own log gives me the output "Directory created: false", and I get the following error:

```
/storage/emulated/0/myApp/test.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

What else can be the problem here but the permissions? I am testing on a nexus 5, Android 6.0.1

Comment: 'dir.mkdirs();'. Check the return value and do not continue if false but stop or return.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Android 6, you have to [request permissions at run time](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html). It's not enough to just have them declared in the Manifest.

Comment: Indeed perfect answer. I was wondering the whole day what the problem here might be... thank you!